# How to export C functions from a Cython DLL?

Tags: python, c, windows, cython

A cythonized module DLL should be usable both from Python and C/C++ progs.
An example Cython file

```
#example.pyx
cpdef public double SQ(double x):
    return x * x
```

is compiled to a .pyd on Windows (.so on Linux) by

```
cythonize -a -i -3 example.pyx
```

However the created DLL doesn't export the SQ function despite the `public` - and a further`api` also won't help.
I'd need to manually edit a `__declspec(dllexport)` into the created .c file like

```
__declspec(dllexport) __PYX_EXTERN_C double SQ(double, int __pyx_skip_dispatch); /*proto*/
```

or play around with an extra `.def` file and link manually. Then it does work, but that's not practical.

Is there a possibility to trigger the `dllexport` from inside the `.pyx`?
Or what is the most practical solution?